# Не передаются данные на сервер в json формате

Tags: javascript, java, servlet, request, xmlhttprequest

При отправке значение в формате json на сервер, сервлет получает их как null. При отправке же данных в другом формате, например, заголовок устанавливаю как `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` и передаю данные как `xhr.send( "command=addAuthor");` все передается верно

js

```
async function addAuthors() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8081/Task1_war/main?command=addAuthor");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var data = JSON.stringify({"authorName": "hey@mail.com", "path": "101010"});
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

servlet, в режиме отладки author=null

```
String author=request.getParameter("authorName")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: отредактировано

Comment: Показанный вами код передаёт json-данные полностью корректно. Ищите проблему в своём сервлете. Например, уверены ли вы, что ваш сервлет в принципе способен обрабатывать json-запросы?

Comment: а как понять, может ли он обрабатывать json

Comment: я же просто должна ее получить с помощью getParameter, разве нет?

Comment: Если разработчики метода getParameter не предусмотрели работу с json-данными — то нет. Но лично я в сервлетах не разбираюсь и дальше уже ничего не подскажу

Answer (score 0):

`getParameter()` предназначен для вычитывания именованных параметров, которые передаются в POST / GET запросах c `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Для обработки JSON нужно вычитать всё тело запроса (request body) в некую строку/буфер, например:

```java
String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Затем следует распарсить эту строку, желательно используя стандартные библиотеки Gson или Jackson, и получить некий объект (POJO, JsonNode, Map<String, String>, и т.п. в зависимости от используемой библиотеки и способа парсинга); и лишь потом у этого объекта уже можно будет вычитать требуемые поля.